# What is this "Log" class?

Tags: c#

I see an application have used `Log.info = "some info"`
where are these logs created by the application ? where can i see that ?

Comment: This question is sorely lacking in information. What application? What is the logging software it is using?

Comment: They have used this log.info to catch the exception in visual studio wiforms c#. I need to know the location of log file created by c#

Comment: right click the variable log->go to definition. right click the class of log->go to definition and see for yourself

Comment: Yep - you've got to find out the type of the object doing the logging, then either post it here, or google it and you might get your answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to monitor which files are written to when you step over this line.

Answer (score 1):

Check for potential configuration settings in App.config.  If it is a 3rd party Logging Framework (e.g. log4net) there may be some clue in the App.config.  Otherwise you'll need to post more info.